# Which tag in html <oU0003Ap> is?

Tags: html, tags

I have seen a special tag `<oU0003Ap> </oU0003Ap>`.

[special tag](https://www.goodreads.com/reader/52414-the-roasters-wall-street-songbook?percent=5.690726&widget=1)

[image]

Which tag in html  is ?

Comment: That looks like HTML that has been mangled in sequence by Microsoft Word, Calibre and whatever was used to make it show up in that site. Also please note that it isn't actual HTML source but just HTML tags inserted as text into a partial HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be Unicode.

U+003A is the colon (:)

So `<oU0003Ap>` should be `<o:p>` like in [What do `<o:p>` elements do anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808968/what-do-op-elements-do-anyway)